# Согласные на стыке приставки и корня

Tags: орфография

На стыке приставки и корня (существует правило) если корень начинается со звонкой согласной, приставка оканчивается также звонкой (то же касается глухих).

Почему в слове "отдам" приставка кончается глухой, а корень начинается со звонкой согласной?

Comment: _При написании_ изменяются _только_ приставки, оканчивающиеся на -з.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Фонетическое чередование** характерно для русского языка. В частности **парные по звонкости-глухости согласные** перед шумными согласными произносятся одинаково с ними (оглушаются или озвончаются).

Но русское правописание фонематическое (смысловое) , а не фонетическое (звуковое). Это означает, что обычно  **такие изменения не отражаются на письме**. Поэтому в слове "отдам" мы озвончаем Т перед Д, но при записи сохраняем **основной (смысловой**) вариант приставки ОТ (школьникам объясняют, что нет приставки ОД, но есть приставка ОТ). Большинство приставок имеют постоянный буквенный состав.

**Но есть исключения — это приставки на З/С.** Именно они пишутся по слуху, то есть фонетическое чередование отражается на письме, например: *истратил, изменил*. Говорится, что существуют приставки ИЗ/ИС, РАЗ/РАС, ВЗ/ВС и т.д.  (Но приставка С имеет только один письменный вариант.)

Таким образом, именно для  приставок на З/С существует правило, которое сформулировано в начале вопроса.